# ampersand(&) and special characters are not working in ORDS print server

Tags: oracle-apex, xsl-fo

Recently Print server has been changed for APEX listener to ORDS Print server.
I am using “`&#0026;`” for ampersand(&) and “`&#x00A7;`” from section sign(§) in xsl-fop.
It used to work fine in APEX Listener however PDF is not getting generated after changing the Print Server.

I am able to replicate same issue in apex.oracle.com.

Workspace: fop_issue

Username: test

Password: Test@123

Created 3 test report queries in Application 132098.
Report Query1:  FOP_WITHOUT_ISSUES ( PDF is generated without issues)
Which contains simple select statement (select ‘test user’ a from dual)  and Report layout is Generic Report Layout.

Report Query2: FOP_WITH_ISSUES_2 (PDF is generated with issues)
Which contains same select statement (select ‘test user’ a from dual)  and Report layout(FOP_WITH_ISSUES_2) is defined with generic Report layout however added “test `&#0026;` user” statement in Report Column Heading.
[image]

If `&#0026;` is taken out and run the report then PDF is generated like below.

[image]

If just ampersand(&) is taken out then PDF is generated like below

[image]

Report Query3: FOP_WITH_ISSUES (PDF is generated with issues)
This Report also contains same select statement(select ‘test user’ a from dual) and Report laoout (FOP_WITH_ISSUES) is defined with Named Columns(XSL-FO) layout. Which is very simple FOP which contains section sign “`&#x00A7;`”

[image]

Removed ampersand (&) from fop then PDF is generated like below.

[image]

Please advice any solution for this issue.
Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1):

`&#0026;` is a decimal numeric character reference to U+001A, which is a non-printing control character. `&#x26;` is a hexadecimal numeric character reference to U+0026 AMPERSAND. However, `&` is the start of an entity reference or a numeric character reference. Any other use of `&` is a syntax error.

If you want to represent "&", use `&amp;`.  That's the predefined entity for the "&" character.  If you really want to use numeric character references for "&", use `&#38;38;`. See https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-predefined-ent.

`&#x00A7;` is a hexadecimal numeric character reference to U?00A7 SECTION SIGN.  I don't know why it's not working for you.  However, your last screenshot includes "U 0047"; i.e., the '+' from your screenshot of the XSLT is missing as well, so you might have something wrong with all of your fonts.